# Replace javascript postback with the expected url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace the following:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl33$ShowLists','DoList|2711|311')
```

with

```
main.aspx?action=listshow&id=2711&row=311#auto
```

Only the digits 2711 and 311 might change and thereforce I want to keep them.
I tried this:

```
var oldHref = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl33$ShowLists','DoList|2711|311')";
var newHref = oldHref.replace(/javascript:__doPostBack\('ctl33\$ShowLists','DoList|(\d+)|(\d+)'\)/, "main.aspx?action=listshow&id=$1&row=$2#auto");
```

I already did some regular expressions, but needless to say that they did not cover my problem, did I forget to escape something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe, `|` (RegExp "OR") has to be escaped as well.

```
var newHref = oldHref.replace(/javascript:__doPostBack\('ctl33\$ShowLists','DoList\|(\d+)\|(\d+)'\)/, "main.aspx?action=listshow&id=$1&row=$2#auto");
```

PS. Instead of using `.replace`, you can also just match the relevant parts of the given string, and concatenate it:

```
var oldHref = "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl33$ShowLists','DoList|2711|311')";
var matches = /(\d+)\|(\d+)/.exec(oldHref);
var newHref = "main.aspx?action=listshow&id=" + matches[1] + "&row="  + matches[2] + "#auto";
```

Comment: Your idea without replace is better, thanks!

I didn't even know about the "or" functionality of the pipe, thanks! It turned out that I actually needed it, since the second match could also be "auto", so I used the pipe there :)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET server forms use POST method be defaults. To use GET method you need to use [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control or implement OnClientClick event handler and change 'document.location.href' property.

Comment: I don't have access to the server, I'm a mere user, so I execute the script after the page has already loaded on my client side.